# Why does my destructor appear to be called more often than the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    static int cnt;
    A()
    { 
        ++cnt; 
        cout<<"constructor:"<<cnt<<endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        --cnt;
        cout<<"destructor:"<<cnt<<endl;
    }
};

int A::cnt = 0;

A f(A x){
    return x;
}
int main(){
    A a0;
    A a1 = f(a0);
    return 0;
}
```

The program will output:

```
constructor:1
destructor:0
destructor:-1
destructor:-2
```

The constructor and destructor don't appear in pairs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! +1 and thank you for providing a complete sample program. See http://SSCCE.ORG for why that was important.

Comment: The copy contructor invoked by `return x;` is apparently optimized away already, but I wonder whether a sufficiently aggressive optimizer could remove the invocation when calling `f` (`x` is passed by value) as well. So that effectively you call the default destructor once and then the copy constructor once.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: that optimization wouldn't conform to the standard, which permits copy constructor elision only in certain circumstances. In all the allowed circumstances, either the source or destination of the elided copy is a temporary.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I see, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 14):

You need to add a copy constructor that increases the counter.

```
A(const A&)
{ 
    ++cnt; 
    cout<<"copy constructor:"<<cnt<<endl;
}
```

If you don't add it explicitly, the compiler generates one that does nothing with the counter `cnt`.

This expression

```
A a1 = f(a0);
```

is creating copies of `a0`, which make use of the copy constructor. The exact number of copies may vary depending on [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), but your `cnt` should be `0` at the end of the program.

**Note**: In C++11, you should also consider the possibility of a compiler generated *move copy constructor*, however, once you declare your own copy constructor, the compiler no longer generates the move version.

Answer (score 5):

You are not tracking **all** constructors, only the default constructor. The compiler has generated a copy constructor and used it a couple of times, accounting for the 2 objects that are listed as destroyed and not as created.

Answer (score 3):

You need to count copy constructor calls as well. In C++11 there are also move constructors that need to be taken into account.