# C++ static counter not increasing correctly

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my destructor appear to be called more often than the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567416/why-does-my-destructor-appear-to-be-called-more-often-than-the-constructor)

I have a `static sCounter` and `int id` to order my instances with id's.

When grouping them in a vector, this works fine.. ID's are setted corrrectly:

```
Task t("1st Task");
Task t2("2nd Task");
    Task t3("3rd Task");

std::vector<Task> myTasks;
myTasks.push_back(t);
myTasks.push_back(t2);
myTasks.push_back(t3);
```

task number one has ID 0, the second one: ID 1 and the third one ID 2.
However, if I do this:

```
std::vector<Task> myTasks;

myTasks.push_back(
   Task("First Task"));
myTasks.push_back(
   Task("Second Task"));
myTasks.push_back(
   Task("Third Task"));
```

The static sCount values starts giving strange results:

the first one gets ID 1, the second also ID 1, and the third gets ID 0.

Why does creating object like this mess with the static counter?

The sCounter gets increased on the constructor, and decreased on the destructor:

```
int Task::sCount = 0;

Task::Task(std::string text) {
    this->setText(text);
    this->setStatus(1);
    time_t now = time(0);
    timestamp = *localtime(&now);
    std::cout << "Count from " << sCount;
    sCount++;
    std::cout << " to --> " << sCount << "\n";
    this->setID(); // set the current sCount to ID
}
Task::~Task() {
    --sCount;
}
```

sCounter is a private static int: `static int sCount;`

Comment: Can you add the code for `Task`?

Comment: I think we need to see the static counter code and how it's called to make any headway here.

Comment: Where is `sCounter` incremented? There's not enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: added the constructor/destructor of Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, each Task instance passed to push_back is a *temporary variable*. This means that its destructor is called once the call to push_back is complete. The destructor then decrements the counter before the next Task is created.

```
myTasks.push_back( Task("First Task") ); // Task's destructor is called before the next line
```

Although the Task is copied into the vector (so the data exists elsewhere in memory), the implicit copy constructor that std::vector uses for this does not increment the counter.

Comment: If get rid of the destructor, it works fine... But is this correct?

Comment: It depends if you need the sCounter to be zero at the end of your program... If so, as Michael suggests you should keep the destructor and implement an *explicit copy constructor* that increments the counter. If the Tasks only ever live inside a container (like the vector), you might better track IDs in the container itself, rather than using constructors/destructors and a static variable.

Answer (score 3):

Destructor works fine, but copy constructor involved in pushing stuff around isn't incrementing counter.

Just implement explicit copy constructor taking care of the counter.

Comment: The second way is calling the destructor before the next task is created... But doing the second way seems like a better way to dynamically create Task's... What would be the best approach?

Comment: I don't know what's your goal. `id` sounds to me like unique identifier and what you doesn't seem to enforce uniqueness. Maybe you should never decrement it instead.